# XPath: Get previous item, filtering by class

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="DivHeaderSizes" data-subgroup="1">
    <img style="display:none" class="help-size-img-colorbox" data-subgroup="1_Man" src="Man.gif">
        <div class="subgroup-description">Jogging</div>
        <div class="help-size-link cboxElement" data-subgroup="1_Man">Tutorial</div>
</div>
    <div style="float: left;" class="DivSizeElement">
        <table data-size="41" class="SizeElement" style="display: none;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="td-label-size">
                        <span class="label-size" data-size="41">41</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="td-label-textbox">
                        <input name="ctl00$CthBody$sizelist$TxtSize_41" type="text" maxlength="4" id="CthBody_sizelist_TxtSize_41" class="txt-Size" data-price="19.50" data-size="41" data-available="0" data-subgroup="1" style="width:30px;">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left;" class="DivSizeElement">
            <table data-size="42" class="SizeElement" style="display: none;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="td-label-size">
                            <span class="label-size" data-size="42">42</span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="td-label-textbox">
                            <input name="ctl00$CthBody$sizelist$TxtSize_S" type="text" maxlength="4" id="CthBody_sizelist_TxtSize_S" class="txt-Size" data-price="19.50" data-size="42" data-available="0" data-subgroup="1" style="width:30px;">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Using Selenium with C# and starting from input element with name

> ctl00$CthBody$sizelist$TxtSize_41

I want the XPath expression to get the text "Jogging". Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the context node is `input[@name='ctl00$CthBody$sizelist$TxtSize_41']`, then the following XPath will select the div containing "Jogging":

```
(preceding::div[@class='subgroup-description'])[1]
```

Or you could use:

```
ancestor::div[1]/preceding-sibling::div[1]/div[@class='subgroup-description']
```